# Как лучше сформулировать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Нет ли в выражении "увековечить в веках" тавтологии?

Comment: Есть, разумеется. Сохраним память о тавтологии в веках!

Answer (score 1):

"Увековечить в веках" является тавтологией.

**Можно использовать следующие выражения**: увековечить или оставить память;  сохранить  память в веках.

В 1795-м Екатерина II приняла решение особо **увековечить** подвиги донских казаков в победоносных войнах.

Коринфяне, напротив того, созидая свои огромные здания, чертоги, храмы, портики и амфитеатры, не думали о доходах, а хотели только **оставить о себе память в веках** и потому не торопились в постройках.

По финансовым же соображениям мэрия решила, что идею **увековечить память** о землепроходцах и основателях Иркутска воплотит памятник Якову Похабову.